# Fusion Tables Experimental

Tags: google-fusion-tables

What exactly does it mean that Google's Fusion Tables is still "Experimental"? I am not familiar with any other Google services that are labeled as "Experimental". Does this mean that its OK to invest time and money developing for this service or does it mean that it will probably get swept up in the next spring cleaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fusion Tables is provided by the [Data Management](http://research.google.com/pubs/DataManagement.html) team in Google Research. This means we do not provide Enterprise level support and currently there is no way to purchase increased support, API quota or storage.

Commercial use is allowed as long as it is within usage governed by the Google Terms of Service and  Google APIs Terms of Service.

For non-commercial use increased API quota can be requested from the Google API Console, and exceptions for storage quota and maximum mappable points can be requested by sending an email to googletables-feedback@google.com.